# Prove that the function $f(x) = \sum_{k =1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(kx)}{2^{k}}$ is infinitely differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Prove that the function $f(x) = \sum_{k  =1}^{\infty}
> \frac{\sin(kx)}{2^{k}}$ is infinitely differentiable

This is a practice problem for an exam I have coming soon. I am trying to study, but I cannot figure out how to do this problem. I think that the correct approach would be to show that the function $f$ is analytic, which implies that $f$ is infinitely differentiable.

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, and how to do it, though.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you could just justify the operation of differentiation term by term. Hint: consider the uniform convergence of such series.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446315/sum-of-cos-theta-frac12-cos2-theta-frac14-cos3-theta-dots

Comment: Think of $x$ as $z$ a complex variable. Then ask if $f(z)$ is analytic.